# AVAssetExportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler returns failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avkit

I'm implementing AVAssetExportSession to trim a video online but always returns failed.

Here is my implementation:

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.ebookfrenzy.com/ios_book/movie/movie.mov";
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:fileURL];
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
NSURL *exportUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"export.m4a"]];

exportSession.outputURL = exportUrl;
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 10);
exportSession.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, time);
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void) {

    switch (exportSession.status)
    {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            /*expor is completed*/
            NSLog(@"Completed!!");
            break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            NSLog(@"failed!!");
            /*failed*/
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}];
```

Any of you knows why this happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to create an `AVAsset` with a remote URL and you need to know that the asset has loaded before you can begin your export.

`AVAsset` conforms to the `AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading` protocol, which means you can observe the `tracks` key and start your export once the value changes:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:myMovieURLString];
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:myURL];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"tracks"] completionHandler:^{

    //Error checking here - make sure there are tracks

    [weakSelf exportAsset:asset];

}];
```

Then you can have your export code in a separate method:

```
- (void)exportAsset:(AVAsset *)asset {

    //Your export code here
}
```

Comment: I implemented you solution and also AVKeyValueStatus inside of loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys block but I always get AVKeyValueStatusUnknown. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

documentsDirectory should be an is exiting path . if it doesn't , exportSession.status will equals to AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed