# How to export asset with remote URL using AVAssetExportSession?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset, avassetexportsession

I want to save video from `AVAsset` which is initialized with remote `URL`. I tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930885/avassetexportsession-exportasynchronouslywithcompletionhandler-returns-failed) solution, but I'm still getting error:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain 
>   Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for
>   this media., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1c424d3b0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain
>   Code=-12109 "(null)"}}

So that's how I'm exporting asset:

```
let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
let filename = UUID().uuidString
let documentDirectory = documentDirectory()
let outputURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)

exporter?.outputURL = outputURL
exporter?.outputFileType = .mp4
exporter?.exportAsynchronously {
    print(exporter?.error)
}
```

And I'm doing that (according to mentioned post) when the `AVAsset` has loaded values:

```
asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["tracks"]) {
    // export here
}
```

Comment: What is exportAsynchronously and where is your completion block?

Comment: It's a function from AVAssetExportSession which exports asset to given url, and the completion block is just printing an error...

Comment: -11838 is `AVErrorOperationNotSupportedForAsset`... what kind of media is your asset ?

Comment: Just video in mp4

Comment: But what are the video and audio codecs ?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: [That Medium article](https://medium.com/@vdugnist/how-to-cache-avurlasset-data-downloaded-by-avplayer-5400677b8b9e) also reports errors when attempting to use AVAssetExportSession for a remote URL.